# using "AND" statement with "SELECT DISTINCT"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a search engine and what i want is to select rows which are different for two columns.

```
$sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name AND surname FROM users");

    while($cek = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu))
    {
        $display = $cek['name']." ".$cek['surname'];

        if(strcmp($written,$display) == 0)
        {
            echo $display;
        }       
    }
```

I am getting Undefined index error for both of them, name and surname.When i delete "AND" statement here, code works fine.  How can i use "AND" here, meaning comparison two columns at the same time?
Thanks

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? Are the name and surname supposed to be different from each other? Or are the name + surname combination supposed to be unique? Or is it something else?

Comment: use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT for more than 1 field;Change it to DISTINCT id;

Comment: name+surname supposed to be unique

Comment: In SQL `AND` is *only* used for a [logical conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) in a `WHERE` (or equivalent clause).

Comment: you can also do `SELECT DISTINCT concat(name,' ',surname) FROM users`, instead of doing it in your *seemingly* PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to pull a `DISTINCT` Name and Surname it should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Surname 
FROM Users
```

<strike>`GROUP BY Name, Surname`</strike>

This will give you results like:

```
  Name | Surname
------------------
  John | Smith
  John | Doe
  Doug | Smith
```

It prevents results like:

```
  Name | Surname
------------------
  John | Smith
  John | Doe
  John | Smith
```

Comment: +1, Indeed.  I believe `DISTINCT` applies to everything in the `SELECT` statement when you use it.

Comment: That is correct, if you wanted a `DISTINCT Name` and a `DISTINCT Surname` then you would need to use a subquery to accomplish this.

Comment: GROUP BY is not necessary if the DISTINCT has been applied

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT for more than 1 field;Change it to DISTINCT id;

change

```
$sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name AND surname FROM users");
```

to

```
$sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM users GROUP BY name, surname");
```

Answer (score 0):

In most databases a `DISTINCT` (or `UNIQUE`) is equivalent to a `GROUP BY ... ORDER BY`, whereas `GROUP BY` by itself is an unordered `DISTINCT`

This:

- ```
  SELECT DISTINCT name, surname 
  FROM users
  ```

Should be equivalent to:

- ```
  SELECT    name, surname 
  FROM      users
  GROUP BY  name, surname
  ORDER BY  name, surname
  ```

Which is similar to:

- ```
  SELECT    name, surname 
  FROM      users
  GROUP BY  name, surname
  ```

---

All of which should give you a unique set of records, but the last should yield the fastest result.

Also, isntead of concatenating in the code, you can also do that in the database:

- ```
  SELECT DISTINCT concat(name,' ',surname)
  FROM users
  ```